# I'm sorry, but I must resign as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

To make a long story short, Stack Exchange is rolling out a new Code of Conduct and enforcing it on moderators in a way that would require action of me that goes against my conscience and, in my view, the best long term interests of this and other sites. I am requesting to resign as moderator because I cannot support the new company policies nor the way they treat their volunteers.

For the long version please see the [somewhat wordier explanation](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/30) I just posted on Christianity's meta site.

I'm sorry it has come to this, and it really has been a privilege to serve this site along with the entire crew of current and past moderators. I will sincerely miss that, and I wish the best for the site.

Comment: I'm sorry to see you step down under these circumstances. Since long before I was hired, I've had the utmost respect for your integrity and wisdom. The work you've done to moderate this site and Christianity has been inspirational in every sense of that word. I hope lifting this responsibility will free you to do even greater things.

Comment: Thank you for those words @JonEricson.

Comment: My apologies for my battling with you which, in retrospect are trivialities and not personal. Peace to you and yours and all success in your new venture.

Comment: @Ruminator, Thank you sir.

Comment: Thanks for all your hard work and input Caleb.Wishing you all the best for the future.

Answer (score 11):

It is a very sad thing for the community here that you are no longer moderator. This site is particularly difficult to moderate, and you have made a major positive impact since agreeing to help [back in 2012](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/148/revisions).

During the period when we were fellow moderators I was conscious that our style of moderation was different, and also that your style was sorely needed!

I am currently very concerned for the future of this site and others like it. I fear they may not survive, despite the work you and others have put in over the years, building bridges between those with apparently irreconcilable differences. Let's hope I'm wrong and others as dedicated as yourself will be able to work with the community here to keep this special niche of the internet viable.

I hope you do not feel that your efforts here have been wasted: they have not. Nothing is wasted, whatever the outcome.

I wish you all the best for the future.

Answer (score 5):

#### The crux of the biscuit: the way they treat their volunteers

People offer up their time, talent, and experience to make a useful on online library, which makes SE/SO money. This is true for the content providers (answers) and mods who herd the cats to keep the Signal to Noise ration down.  For that good faith effort to be spurned is bitter to see  happening. I am now glad that I did not succeed in being elected as a mod on either site where I ran.

I rarely post here but I read with some frequency.  As I noted in C.SE, Caleb, you've done a fine job and your great gift of offering your time and talents is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm upset by the direction SE is taking<sup>`1`</sup>, and sad to see how this direction has impacted your ability to participate,<sup>`2`</sup> since you have been an excellent moderator here.<sup>`3`</sup> I wish you all the best, whatever direction the Lord takes you.

<sup>`1`</sup> This is the first I've read about it, but then I don't spend much time on meta; but I read your longer C.SE and also Monica's that you linked to.

<sup>`2`</sup>And perhaps mine in the future.

<sup>`3`</sup>And now I am a bit apprehensive about the types of moderators we may get here.