# Hide or delete posts

Tags: discussion, delete

What are the rules on hiding or deleting posts?

I just gtot a post deleted by @curiousdanni. It was probably no a great answer but I would have preferred to have it hidden, so that I can see what it has been and whether it is worth while improving it.

I would expect to have an answer deleted if it is offensive (and I would apologise if someone has understood it in this sense) and I would expect to see it hidden if it is providing information that is not related to the question or lacking quality.

Comment: Related: The search parameter *deleted:yes* retrieves one's answers (and presumably questions as well). I'm mindful of Steve Taylor's explanation. I'm just mentioning this apropos of the topic of deleted posts.

Answer (score 2):

have you checked out the recent Meta post [Why has my Reputation Score Suddenly Changed](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3865)?

Do you know which question it was? The moderation team is currently doing a substantial prune of falsified content, where we're having to delete more than we usually would under regular circumstances. It's likely that the Question in view here was asked, answered and accepted by a single user under the guise of separate accounts, and was not a genuine question. We're trying to preserve high quality or useful content wherever possible, but are having to balance that with other concerns.

Please rest assured that this is a "one time" activity and we are otherwise extremely cautious about removing content. Please do raise a Flag or post a Meta question like this if you have any concerns.

Edit: Sorry, this post wasn't one of this batch - have [found it and undeleted](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/59514/13311) so you can remediate if you want. Normally we would add a "post notice" and give you time to address before Deletion - apologies for not giving you more notice. Thanks for flagging.

Comment: ok. It was not an answer, just an aspect. I have deleted it myself...

Comment: @Jeschu - excellent, thanks for confirming and for raising the concern in the first place